# Jest error "Cannot find module" even though package is installed

Tags: typescript, jestjs, package.json, vite, ts-jest

I recently cleaned up and updated a private package to be built with Vite.

Before the cleanup the package.json looked like this:

```
{
  "name": "@myRegistry/my-package",
  "version": "7.15.1",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "typings": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --outDir dist/",
    "build:docs": "typedoc ./index.ts",
    "test": "jest",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "portable-fetch": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^13.13.0",
    "jest": "^25.4.0",
    "ts-jest": "^25.4.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.20.36",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the new and current package.json. I did the Vite scaffolding and only changed what I had to:

```
{
  "name": "@myRegistry/my-package",
  "version": "7.16.0",
  "type": "module",
  "files": [
    "build"
  ],
  "main": "./build/my-package.js",
  "module": "./build/my-package.js",
  "types": "./build/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./build/my-package.js"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "docs": "typedoc ./src/index.ts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typedoc": "^0.23.21",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4",
    "vite": "^3.2.3",
    "vite-plugin-dts": "^1.7.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0"
  }
}
```

This package is installed in two projects that also use Vite.

One does unittests with Vitest and I can run unittests in that package without problem.

The other project uses Jest for unittests, and in that project I get errors like this for every file that imports the package:

```
Cannot find module '@myRegistry/my-package' from 'src/fileToTest.ts'


Require stack:
  src/fileToTest.ts
  tests/unit/fileToTest.spec.ts
```

Here is the jest.config.js of that project:

```
module.exports = {
  coverageReporters: ['cobertura'],
  moduleDirectories: [
    'node_modules',
    'src'
  ],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'ts', 'vue'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
  },
  modulePaths: ['<rootDir>', '<rootDir>/node_modules'],
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm',
  rootDir: './',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>tests/setup.ts'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  testMatch: ['**/tests/unit/**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)'],
  transform: {
    '.*\\.(vue)$': '@vue/vue2-jest',
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/']
}
```

I just can't figure out what I'm missing and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that we removed CommonJS support from what I called `my-package`. Rebuilding the package with CommonJS support solves that problem. That or just ditching jest in favor of vitest.